# Can't write string to txt file because another file is accesing it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a Chat-Bot of sorts and I am trying to code in a 'learning' functionality. I am fairly new to coding but I suspect that my problem has to do with me not closing a read stream but I have no idea how. I would like help on finding the most efficient way to solve this difficulty. Here is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static bool isRecording = false;
    static bool isTraining = false;
    static bool shutdown = false;

    static string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "memory.txt");

    static string inputValue;
    static string outputValue = " ";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Computer: Hello! I am MyAI Version 2.0.");
        Console.WriteLine("Training?");
        inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        inputValue = inputValue.ToLower();
        inputValue = inputValue.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '.', ',', ':', ';', '*' });


        if (inputValue == "yes")
        {
            isTraining = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Training mode set to true.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            isTraining = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Training mode set to false");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.Clear();
        CollectInput();

    }

    static void CollectInput()
    {
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path);
        while (!shutdown)
        {
            Console.Write("User: ");
            inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
            inputValue = inputValue.ToLower();
            inputValue = inputValue.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '.', ',', ':', ';', '*' });
            StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

            if (inputValue == "hi" || inputValue == "hello" || inputValue == "greetings")
            {
                outputValue = "hi";
            }
            else if (inputValue.Contains("how are you"))
            {
                outputValue = "good";
            }
            else
            {
                if (isTraining)
                {
                    if (isRecording)
                    {
                        //This is where I would like to write inputValue to path
                        isRecording = false;
                    }
                }
                if (File.ReadAllLines(path).Contains(inputValue))
                {
                    outputValue = File.ReadLines(path)
                    .SkipWhile(line => line != inputValue)
                    .Skip(1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (inputValue.Contains("?"))
                    {
                        outputValue = inputValue;
                        //This is where I would like to write inputValue to path
                        isRecording = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outputValue = "what about it?";
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Write("Computer: ");
            Console.WriteLine(outputValue);
            outputValue = " ";    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `File.ReadLines`, [`File.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open(v=vs.110).aspx) the file once and then read/write to it with the same handle.

Comment: File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
                        outputValue = File.ReadLines(path)
                        .SkipWhile(line => line != inputValue)
                        .Skip(1)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @Mattinthehat You're still opening new file handle at `outputValue = File.ReadLines(path)`. Search for methods that use the handle that is returned by `File.Open`. I think your IDE or compiler should warn you that you're discarding the return value of `File.Open`

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am still new and i don't know a better way to redo that part of code. Basically what it does is it checks the file for the input then if found takes the line below it.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx, File.ReadLines allows you to start enumerating the lines of the file before they are read completely. What that says to me is that the file is likely left open for some period of time following the start of your enumerations.

If you don't need that asynchronous behavior, just switch to File.ReadAllLines. You can iterate them similarly and you should be able to write to the file with File.AppendAllLines.

Comment: Does `File.ReadAllLines` close the file when it's done reading?

Comment: OK I switched to ReadAllLines and added a writetext.Close() function to the write method. It works now! heres the write function   using (TextWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writetext.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                writetext.Write(inputValue);
                writetext.Close();
            }

Comment: @JohnSmith, apparently so.

Comment: @Mattinthehat Awesome! I'm glad the solution worked!

Comment: My Ai works now planning to add more functions later; learning c++